# prebuilt .so library not recognized in Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I have been given a .so library called libremote_client.so

The library has a function called getInstance which returns an Object type IRemote. 
I have copied the .so file into my AndroidStudio project in the

app/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/libremote_client.so

In my Activity I declare the following at class level

```
public native IRemote getInstance();
```

Unfortunately AndroidStudio cannot resolve the reference type IRemote. I obviously have not included the prebuilt .so file correctly in my project.

I think i may need to add some dependencies in my Gradle but i'm not sure where to start.

Below is my gradle file, can anyone show me how to add the .so file to my project correctly so my Activity can resolve the IRemote reference type?

Thanks in advance

Matt

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"



    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "devreach.co.uk.devreach"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'jniLibs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile files('libs/sqlcipher.jar')
    compile project(':ScreenSharingSDK')
    compile files('libs/joda-time-2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile project(':edm')
    compile project(':kcm')
    compile project(':rc')

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to gradle:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jni.srcDirs = [] 
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jniLibs'
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi i get the following when building project. Error:(40, 0) Could not find property 'jniLibs' on source set 'main'.

Comment: did you copy jniLibs folder to main folder in your project ?

Comment: I'm new to NDK and Gradle so i'm not sure how to copy jniLibs folder to main folder. What do i need to put in the Gradle to achieve this?

Comment: Basically i've been given a .so library and a header file from Samsung. The library captures the dirty region of the screen using framebuffer. The thread below is the converstaion i've had with Samsung. I'm not sure how to configure Gradle or even create the jni folder. The guy at Samsung says i need to include a JAR which i have, place the .so in armeabi folder which i have. Then create some native methods in the Activity which will call the methods in the cpp file. The thing is i don't know how to create the cpp file. I've done some reading and it seems that if i place the

Comment: .h file in the jni folder then execute javah in the terminal window, this will create a cpp file for me. Can you give me any guidance? https://seap.samsung.com/developer/forum-topic/how-use-remotecontol-api

Comment: but before i do any of that i need to find out how to copy jniLibs folder to main folder in my project

Comment: We have two option for native library: jni.srcDirs contain all project with c code, we need contine setup ndk to build these project, and jniLibs.srcDir is path to folder contain .so file. If you have c code you need some setup

Comment: you can copy jniLibs directly to main folder in project, no special for this

Answer (score 0):

Whoever gave you the .so file forgot to give you the associated Java files, including IRemote and possibly more. Without `IRemote.java` interface class, how could you or the compiler know what methods can be called and what data are returned?

Also I've noticed that you have the line

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'jniLibs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

this is not needed and can be removed.